# Swagger Version for Spring 3 and Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger, springfox

I want to documenting a REST API with Swagger and Spring MVC,

And I find out that Spring 3 only can use Swagger V1

```
        <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
```

when I add @ApiParam in front of @RequestBody , do not display completely in Data Type.

Finally I choose Swagger V2 in Spring 4

I add some dependency and change, as below .

```
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <artifactId>4.1.6.RELEASE</artifactId>
```

Now can display any API info when I needs,

> 1. But still no idea why Spring 3 only can use SwaggerV1
> 2. and the difference between the Spring 3 & 4 when use Swagger V2
> 3. why Spring 3 not need spring-web ,but Spring 4 need

If need any information , please tell me

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: SpringFox is not a product and is an OSS project. Im one of the maintainers of the project and currently the only active maintainer.

Having said that, let me answer some of your questions.

> But still no idea why Spring 3 only can use SwaggerV1

As a policy, the current actively maintained version is one minor version behind the latest version of spring. Swagger v1 is quite old, so when swagger 2 was released we actively moved to a newer version of spring and the last version that supports spring 3 is `1.0.2`. This follows the same guidelines that spring projects like `spring-hateoas` follow.

> and the difference between the Spring 3 & 4 when use Swagger V2

The difference is that spring 3 is not really a supported version for `springfox` v2.x. The officially tested version of spring is `4.1.7.RELEASE` for `v2.2.2`.

> why Spring 3 not need spring-web ,but Spring 4 need

This is because we spring is a `provided dependency` of springfox. So library consumers of can provide any version `> 4.1` and the library would just work. This was not the case in spring 3 because we shipped the springfox library with the spring dependencies.